# Skip specified Python unit-test from command line

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line

I have bunch of unit-tests in my unit-test file. However, one of the tests I would like to skip **only** when running the unit-tests from command line. I know how to always skip it (`@unittest.skip`), but I want to somehow skip it only when running the unit-test file from command line. Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
test_all_my_tests.py -exclude test_number_five()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.
One idea could be command with arguments and in the arguments specify which tests to skip.
Then in your script you would parse the passed arguments and call your tests accordingly.

Your input would look like:
test_all_my_tests.py -exclude 5

and in the python script it would check for a "-exclude" argument and take the following argument as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at `@unittest.skipIf()` or even implement your own [skip-decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

### Example

Here is a working example, where I implemented a custom decorator

```
def skipIfOverCounter(obj):
```

This decorator is attached to all tests like this:

```
@skipIfOverCounter
def test_upper(self):
```

The decorator increments a count and compares it to the console argument.

### Output

Implemented 3 unit tests:

- test_upper()
- test_isupper()
- test_split()

The I called `python .\unittests.py 0`

```
Skipped test 0 
Ran 'test_isupper'
Ran 'test_split'
```

With param = 1: `python .\unittests.py 1`

```
Skipped test 1
Ran 'test_split'
Ran 'test_upper'
```

Skip the last test: `python .\unittests.py 2`

```
Skipped test 2 
Ran 'test_isupper' 
Ran 'test_upper'
```

### Full working sample

```
import sys
import unittest

SKIP_INDEX = 0
COUNTER = 0

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    SKIP_INDEX = int(sys.argv.pop())

def skipIfOverCounter(obj):
    global COUNTER
    global SKIP_INDEX
    if SKIP_INDEX == COUNTER:
        print(f"Skipped test {COUNTER}")
        COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
        return unittest.skip("Skipped test")
    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
    return obj

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    @skipIfOverCounter
    def test_upper(self):
        print("Ran 'test_upper'")
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    @skipIfOverCounter
    def test_isupper(self):
        print("Ran 'test_isupper'")
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    @skipIfOverCounter
    def test_split(self):
        print("Ran 'test_split'")
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You could even extend this by adapting the decorator to only execute the first two tests or something like this